# Lost all sms data but database seems to be in the folder

Tags: sms, restore, handcent-sms

I own an HTC desire(android 2.3.5) and suddenly the phone rebooted, and after a minute, it rebooted again (I hadn't typed in the pin)...
When I opened my sms app (handcent) I got no messages...

I've searced in `/data/data/com.handcent.nextsms` and found a `.db` file of 6MB...so it must be my sms...

What can I do to restore my sms?

Comment: If handcent stores the SMS in its own database, the usual SMS-backup/restore apps won't be much help. I don't use handcent, so I don't know if it offers a backup itself -- but if, you might want to restore a previous backup (make a copy of the `.db` file before cannot hurt). You could also copy the `.db` file to your computer to get the messages out of it with e.g. [SQLiteman](http://sqliteman.com/), though that wouldn't be a real "restore"...